# How to Triggering code in background in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I want to trigger specific code snippet at everyday 10.00AM while app will minimized pls help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Alarm Manager Class.

You can find suitable example [HERE](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129).

Comment: but i want to execute in activity,any thread concept is there to execute code

Comment: You can call activity instead of broadcast using PendingIntent.getActivity instead of PendingIntent.getBroadcast

Comment: i know , but i want to execute main class, i write alarm manager in that main class, is there possible to call code in main class using alarm manager

Comment: You need to create another activity and write all the code in that which you want to execute at 10 Am

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is setting up an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) that will fire your intent at the time you set it to.Inside your intent you can do whatever code you want.Else setting up a background service could be a good alternative,even tough takes a little more coding